# How to get path of a file inside created android directory in raw folder in android studio

Tags: android, webview

Hey respectful programmers, I created a folder name as HTML pages inside the res folder in my android app. [You can see that in this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zMZd6.png). So I want the address of HTML file inside htmlPages folder. So that I can open the Html page in web view without needing an internet connection in my android app.

can you give me the address of the Html page so that I can open it in webview? Thanks in advance.

I already tried one way, you can see in the image but it's not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the files in **assets** folder. You can access them in webview using URL like:

file:///android_asset/contact.html

So in your project, inside **main** folder create **assets** folder and put your contanct.html there.

Comment: yes, I just found this way, by the way, thanks for caring.

Answer (score 0):

I found another solution to this problem. 
I created an asset folder inside the app directory and then pasted my HTML file there
Adress for the HTML page is like:
`webview.loadurl("file:///android_asset/contact.html")`

If you are doing the same mistake of creating a folder in the res folder then don't do this. This is not a good practice here.